# Should I use "in" or "of"?

Tags: british-english, spoken-english

Which one is correct

> This is the last November of our college life.
>
> This is the last November in our college life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is incorrect as you can’t be *in your college life* as college life is not an object.

In the first one you are not referring to it as an object so it is correct